# First time using packages - Symbols from other classes not recognized

Tags: java, package

Hi everyone thanks in advance for your help. I have code saved across several files and I'm trying to use a package to access and call them to create objects. But when I try to create the object, it says that the symbol is not recognized. I'm not sure what is wrong as I have never used packages before. If someone could help me to some resources that might help me solve the problem.

[This is how I have my files set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2DiA.png)

[These are the errors that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isiv4.png)

Here is the code so you don't have to open the image:

```
Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        chessPiece myPawn = new pawn(chess_piece_type.PAWN, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);
        ^
  symbol:   class chessPiece
  location: class Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism
Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        chessPiece myPawn = new pawn(chess_piece_type.PAWN, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);
                                ^
  symbol:   class pawn
  location: class Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism
Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        chessPiece myKnight = new knight(chess_piece_type.KNIGHT, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);
        ^
```

All the errors that I am getting are similar to these errors.

I tried to call the constructors from the classes that are named like chess piece to create a chess  piece in my main code.

Here is the example of one of my classes where the constructor is initialized. Most of the other classes with constructors are similar so the syntax shouldn't change a lot.

This is the bishop class.

```
// package 
package Lab_3; // UPDATE
// import
import Lab_3.Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism.chess_piece_type;
import Lab_3.Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism.chess_piece_color;
import Lab_3.Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism.chess_piece_columns;

// bishop class
class bishop extends chessPiece {

    // initialize a private chess_piece_type for the name
    private chess_piece_type piece_name;
    // initialize a private chess_piece_type for the color
    private chess_piece_color color;
    // initialize a private chess_piece_type for the x-coord
    private chess_piece_columns column;
    // initialize a private int for the y-coord
    private int row;

    // empty constructor
    public bishop() {
        // default values
        this.piece_name = chess_piece_type.BISHOP;
        this.color = chess_piece_color.WHITE;
        this.column = chess_piece_columns.A;
        this.row = 0;
    }

    // constructor with parameters for each class field
    public bishop(chess_piece_type name, chess_piece_color color, chess_piece_columns x_coord, int y_coord) {
        // set values
        this.piece_name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.column = x_coord;
        this.row = y_coord;
    }

    // getter method for color
    public chess_piece_color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    // getter method for column
    public chess_piece_columns getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    // getter method for row
    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    // setter method for column
    public void setColumn(chess_piece_columns x_coord) {
        this.column = x_coord;
    }

    // setter method for row
    public void setRow(int y_coord) {
        this.row = y_coord;
    }
```

This is my main:

```
// package
package Lab_3;

// imports
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

// main class
public class Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism {

    // everyone used this
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create a pawn object
        chessPiece myPawn = new pawn(chess_piece_type.PAWN, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);

        // create a knight object
        chessPiece myKnight = new knight(chess_piece_type.KNIGHT, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);

        // create a rook object
        chessPiece myRook= new rook(chess_piece_type.ROOK, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);

        // create a bishop object
        chessPiece myBishop = new bishop(chess_piece_type.BISHOP, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);

        // create a queen object
        chessPiece myQueen = new queen(chess_piece_type.QUEEN, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);

        System.out.println(myQueen.verifyTarget(chess_piece_columns.E, 3)); // WORKS

        // create a king object
        chessPiece myKing = new king(chess_piece_type.KING, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);

        System.out.println(myKing.verifyTarget(chess_piece_columns.A, 5)); // WORKS

        System.out.println("Testing create chess piece method");
        chessPiece test = chessPiece.create_chess_piece(chess_piece_type.PAWN, chess_piece_color.BLACK, chess_piece_columns.A, 7);

        System.out.println(test.verifyTarget(chess_piece_columns.A, 6));
        System.out.println("");
}
```

I just expected the objects to be created with the constructors that I am using on the other classes. I will need to use them to simulate chess moves.

Comment: Run from the directory above `Lab_3` and use `java Lab_3.Lab_3_Chess_Pieces_with_Hierarchy_and_Polymorphism`. That should work, assuming that you have a `chessPiece.class` file in the `Lab_3` directory.

Comment: You need to see to your naming as your code is [difficult to read](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: Your main class does not import `chessPiece` or any of its subclasses, and they aren’t in the same package as the main class, so the compiler doesn’t know what those names mean.

Comment: @VRG isn't cessPiece getting imported through the package? How can I make sure that it gets included in the package?

Comment: If you’re asking whether subpackages are automatically imported, the answer is no.  A subpackage has no special relationship to a parent package whatsoever, other than appearing to have some initial common characters in the package name.